# Selenium does not return all results. How to solve this?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get the columns, Q.No, Ministry, Member, and Subject fields from all 79072 records in the table [here](http://loksabhaph.nic.in/Questions/qsearch15.aspx?lsno=16). But my code to scrape data from that table returns incomplete results.

In the webpage, the button to show all records is broken, so I'm retrieving the records by having my script click the Next button and do this in a loop until it retrieves all the records. However, every time I run the script, it appears to quit halfway through after retrieving a random number of records. I thought this might be because the page takes longer to load sometimes so, I have tried increasing the number of seconds my script has to wait before attempting to scrape data, but that did not help at all.

Here is my script.

```
 url = "http://loksabhaph.nic.in/Questions/qsearch15.aspx?lsno=16"
 chrome_options = Options()
 chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
 driver.implicitly_wait(3)
 driver.get(url)
 while True:
     try:
         qno = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tblMember"]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/*/td[1]/a[2]')
         qty = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tblMember"]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/*/td[2]/a[2]')
         min = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tblMember"]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/*/td[4]/a[2]')
         mem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tblMember"]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/*/td[5]/a[2]')
         sub = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tblMember"]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/*/td[6]/a[2]')
         for i in range(4):
             print(qno[i].text + "\t" + qty[i].text + "\t" + min[i].text + "\t" + mem[i].text + "\t" + sub[i].text)
         driver.find_element_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_cmdNext").click()
         time.sleep(5)
     except:
         break
 driver.quit()
```

How can I make sure that my script retrieves all the data?

Also, let me know if there is another way to retrieve this data or if you have any general comments about the code itself. I'm teaching myself how to code so I'd appreciate your feedback.

Edit: Based on pointers from pcalkins and supputuri, I added an "presence of element" and caught the exception. Here is the updated script.

```
while True:
    try:
        qno = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tblMember"]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/*/td[1]/a[2]')
        qty = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tblMember"]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/*/td[2]/a[2]')
        min = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tblMember"]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/*/td[4]/a[2]')
        mem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tblMember"]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/*/td[5]/a[2]')
        sub = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_tblMember"]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/*/td[6]/a[2]')
        for i in range(len(qno)):
            print(qno[i].text + "\t" + qty[i].text + "\t" + min[i].text + "\t" + mem[i].text + "\t" + sub[i].text)
        driver.find_element_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_cmdNext").click()
        myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ContentPlaceHolder1_tblMember')))
#        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

When I ran this updated script, I managed to retrieve about 27000 records after which I got this,

> Message: timeout
>    (Session info: headless chrome=74.0.3729.157)
>    (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6  (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 4.13.0-36-generic x86_64)

Comment: post the exception you receive here...  from a quick look at the page there are some events firing on a "ready" state... there is also page validation which I think stores a clean state.  Possibly part of the issue, but very hard to tell without knowing the exception.

Comment: Questions: Do you see the loading icon? Does the qno change when you navigate to next page. If the answer for either of these yes, then you can write the logic to wait until the loading icon/ current qno not displayed.